# Sync Photostreams from different Apple ID's to the same PC

Tags: icloud, windows, photo-stream

I've got a great setup when it comes to backing up the photos I take with my iPhone.  They are synced to iCloud with Photostream, and then iCloud pushes them down to my PC.  My PC runs a job in the middle of the night to backup this folder offsite, and all of this requires very little maintenance or thought.

However, we recently got an iPad for my wife and I'd like to add her Photostream into the mix.  I want Photostreams from both devices to end up on my PC eventually so they can be backed up.  The part I have not figured out yet is how to push Photostreams from two separate iCloud accounts to the same PC.  We use the same account for App Store purchases, but we have different accounts for everything else and we'd like to keep it that way.  Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: I just make it a comment since you don't say if your wife also has a PC, if she does set it up so that her PC pull's her photo's down but saves them to a network folder that physically exists on your PC.

Answer (score 1):

My thought: create separate user accounts for you and your wife on your PC. Or create a Virtual Machine. I don't believe you'll find a simpler option for this. iCloud Control Panel is your only real choice for getting PhotoStream onto your PC.

Answer (score -1):

I was searching for this too and found a nice video at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VJHEoyPN-9o
I haven't tried it yet, but it seems like it should work.

Comment: I'm unclear why this was downvoted as the video gives step-by-step instructions on how to resolve @jdickson's problem: User has one PC and two iCloud accounts that they want to sync both iCloud accounts' Photostreams to the PC.

Comment: @BrianM. Because if the link is dead (e.g. video is removed), then this answer won't be useful anymore. Instead, quote the content of the video to preserve the content.

Comment: The basic idea from the video is to use the iCloudc client under a different user account using the "Run As" function. This allows to log into the second iCloud acct and configure the photo sync. Then the three EXEs applephotostreams.exe, icloudservices.exe and ubd.exe need to be run under the other Windows acct after every start. You could use AutoIt for that. Sorry, I don't have the time right now to transcribe the video as a step-by-step answer.